# How insert a id param in form ajax to be compatible with ie 11

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form to update data from a website that i am developing , and works fine on chrome, but on internet explorer 11 i recive a error of invalid character on the line of "chamadoid"

url: `/chamados/${chamadoId}`,

whats is the proper way to set a id inside ajax url to make it work on ie?

```
function atualizarChamado() {
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);

    const chamadoId = $(this).data('chamado-id');
    
    $.ajax({
        url: `/chamados/${chamadoId}`,
        method: "PUT",
        data: {
            nome: $('#nome').val(),
            chamado: $('#chamado').val(),
            ativocpu: $('#ativocpu').val(),
            ativomonitor: $('#ativomonitor').val(),
            endereco: $('#endereco').val(),
            numero: $('#numero').val(),
            cep: $('#cep').val(),
            senha: $('#senha').val(),
            transporte: $('#transporte').val(),
            acionamento: $('#acionamento').val(),
            status: $('#status').val(),
            bairro: $('#bairro').val(),
            obs: $('#obs').val(),
            office: $('#office').val(),      
            ramal: $('#ramal').val(),
            logindac: $('#logindac').val(),
            re: $('#re').val(),
            ativoretornomonitor: $('#ativoretornomonitor').val(),
            ativoretornocpu: $('#ativoretornocpu').val(),
            perifericomouse: $('#perifericomouse').val(),
            perifericoteclado: $('#perifericoteclado').val(),
            perifericohead: $('#perifericohead').val(),
            perifericorede: $('#perifericorede').val(),
            analistafield: $('#analistafield').val(),
            gerenteoperador: $('#gerenteoperador').val()
        }
    }).done(function() {
        Swal.fire('Sucesso!', 'Publicação criada com sucesso!', 'success').then(function() {window.location = `/chamados/${chamadoId}/editar`;})
    }).fail(function() {
        Swal.fire("Ops...", "Erro ao editar a publicação!", "error");
    }).always(function() {
        $('#atualizar-chamado').prop('disabled', false);
    })
}
```

Comment: change it to and ```url: '/chamados/' + chamadoId``` and ```window.location = "/chamados/" + chamadoId + "/editar"```  because ` is not supported by IE11

Answer (score 0):

Just use + like that

```js
// ...
url: '/chamados/' + chamadoId
// ...
```